# Trying to generate a timed connection for serial device ttys0 on unix-system

Tags: c++, boost-asio

i am trying to generate a class for reading from a specific serial device.

For the start process it is necessary to send a char '1', then i have to wait for a response (254 and 255).

Within a period of 10 milliseconds i must sent the next command to the device, but this time the command length is 5 char.

When the communication hasn´t been send in the correct time, the device will run into a timeout and is sending me 255,255,255,2,4.

So i need different sizes of reading and the most importing thing for me is a timeout for the communication, cause otherwise the system will stop working by missing some values.

Therefore i have tried to generate a class using boost::asio::async_read.

It is working in the correct way, i can define the timeout,also the size of bytes to be read. When the device isn´t sending the correct size, the routine is going to be left.

But only the first time, when i try it a second time, the device isn´t sending me something. I have tried to use .open again, but it isn´t solving the issue. Also deactivating the close-function isn´t solving the issue, then the routine is running into an error.

Can someone give me a small tip for my issue. Maybe i am to blind to see my problem.... Bernd

```
ConnectionWithTimeout::ConnectionWithTimeout(int timeout_)
    : timer_(io_service_, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(timeout_))
    , serial_port_(io_service_) {
    }

void ConnectionWithTimeout::ReadNumberOfChars(int numberOfCharactersToRead_)
{
    buffer_.resize(numberOfCharactersToRead_);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCharactersToRead_; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Clear Buffer[" << i << "]" << std::endl;
        buffer_[i] = 0;
    }
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&::ConnectionWithTimeout::Stop, this));
    //async read from serial port
    boost::asio::async_read(serial_port_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), 
    boost::bind(&ConnectionWithTimeout::ReadHandle, this, 
    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    io_service_.run();
}

void ConnectionWithTimeout::Stop() {
    std::cout << "Connection is being closed." << std::endl;
    serial_port_.close();
    std::cout << "Connection has been closed." << std::endl;
}
void ConnectionWithTimeout::ReadHandle(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
    if (ec) {
        std::cout << "The amount of data is to low: " << ec << std::endl;
        for (std::vector<char>::iterator it = buffer_.begin();
             it != buffer_.end(); ++it)
        {
            std::cout << int(*it) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "The amount of data is correct: " << ec << std::endl;
        for (std::vector<char>::iterator it = buffer_.begin(); it != 
             buffer_.end(); ++it)
         {
            std::cout << int(*it) << std::endl;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Within a period of 10 milliseconds" I only know that most operating systems have problems guaranteeing you such times, e.g. Microsoft says something about 15ms as usual lower limit, especially in user land code.  So you can only try to give the char '1' and rest send command in one buffer i.e. one call to asio, so its the serial drivers realm to be in that time limit.